# UIImagePickerController and Push Segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIImagePickerController that is presented modally from a home screen. Now my understanding is that UIImagePickerController is a subclass of UINavigationController and acts as the root view controller. So I can easily do this:

```
@interface SCTCameraViewController : UIImagePickerController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self setDelegate:self];
```

Then calling `[self pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];` works fine and goes to the specified view controller just fine. There's one weird thing that happens where a custom UIButton I have on the SCTViewController sticks around with the next view controller that I push on. I can easily just call `[button removeFromSuperView];` no problem, I'm just really curious as to why that button sticks around and stays on top of both the UIImagePickerController and the view controller that I push onto the stack. It's gotta be something weird and technical about navigation but I'd love to know the answer if anyone has any idea.

So my main issue. On my storyboard, I have a push segue that connects my UIImagePickerController and the view controller I want to push onto the navigation stack. However when I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerToPush" sender:self];`, my app crashes and throw this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'cutoutViewModal'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

I was under the impression that the UIImagePickerController is a navigation controller but I'm clearly mistaken. Do I have to explicitly have Navigation Controller in my Storyboard and connect the root view controller to my UIImagePickerController? I tried that and didn't have any luck unfortunately.

Anyone have any idea what's going on and how I fix that? I'm more than happy to just use `[self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`, I would just rather understand why the other way doesn't work the way I would expect it to.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: In the storyboard I went to

> Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Which hooked everything up nicely but when I tried to navigate to the root view controller, the XCode debugging panel spun for a bit and then crashed with a bad access error.

Comment: Do you have a segue called "viewControllerToPush" and another (mentioned in the error) called "cutoutViewModal"?

Comment: Docs say of UIImagePickerController: "This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing". Heed and obey.

Comment: Oh they're the same one. Should I look into using an AVCapture Session instead?